# How to get all the paths of a binomial tree

Tags: options, programming, binomial-tree

I'm trying to implement a pricing method for exotic options based on binomial tree's. The problem i'm having is that i'm not being able to generate all the paths of the tree. I have the following code in python that generates the tree but haven't been able to extract all the paths from it.

```
import numpy as np
risk_free = 0.1
spot = 50
volatility = 0.4
T = 3/12
steps = 3
dt = T/steps
Up = np.exp(volatility*np.sqrt(dt))
Down = 1 / Up
p = (np.exp(risk_free*dt)-Down)/(Up-Down)
q = 1-p

dpowers = Down ** np.arange(steps,-1,-1)
upowers = Up ** np.arange(0,steps+1)
# steps + 1 because at the end we have steps + 1 prices
W = spot*dpowers*upowers

# backward valuation
for i in np.arange(steps, 0,-1):
    Si = spot*dpowers[(steps-i+1):steps+1]*upowers[0:i]
    W = np.vstack((np.append(np.repeat(0,steps-i+1),Si),W))
Tree = W.T
```

Comment: A Path though a binomial tree is just a sequence of letters U or D of length $N$. For example for $N=3$ the possible paths are "DDD, DDU, DUD, DUU, UDD, UDU, UUD, UUU" . There are $2^N$ of them. If you are familiar with the generation of binary numbers, you can program this easily (but here 0 is replaced by D and 1 is replaced by U).

Comment: @noob2 Yeah I new that i had 2^N paths and how they are calculated. To be honest I'm not familiar with generating binary numbers, will look at it.

Comment: By extracting, you mean using the tree generated in `Tree`? Because the paths I get when running your code look reasonable. Have a look at some of [my old code](https://github.com/bobjansen/Prycing/blob/master/options/binom.py) for a working implementation of binomial tree's and the Longstaff Schwarz method.

Comment: @Bob Jansen I now the `Tree` is correct thats part of the code i have for american options, and yeah would like to extract all the paths from object `Tree`. as noob2 mentions the 2^N paths and associate each path to all the nodes in the tree

Comment: If you're really interested in the paths, I wouldn't set it up this way but just make all combinations of UD as @noob2 explains. Basically an $2^N \times N$ matrix where the rows are paths. However, this makes more sense if you're doing Monte Carlo where all paths are independent. with the tree your effectively merging paths into nodes, the first node contains all path, the second layer half etc. If you want to get the $n$th path out of your current tree you could just select it from the tree going up or down in every column.

Comment: @BobJansen yeah already did and then i have the problem that you are saying of relating each path to a specific node. The thing is that the method im trying to code  (hull and white) for lookback options needs all the paths to price the options and i was stuck at the path generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create all the moves you want with the following code, ([taken from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059999/862288)):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
risk_free = 0.1
spot = 50
volatility = 0.4
T = 3/12
steps = 3
dt = T/steps
Up = np.exp(volatility*np.sqrt(dt))
Down = 1 / Up

paths = itertools.product([Up, Down], repeat=steps)
```

You can just loop over this list of list and multiply the current price to get the next price.